# Why is WindsorDependencyResolver unresolvable?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, visual-studio-2013

I installed Castle Windsor via NuGet into my Web API project (VS 2013; Castle 3.2.1).

I added this code:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new WindsorDependencyResolver(container);
```

...from [here](http://blog.mirajavora.com/getting-started-with-asp.net-web-api) to Global.asax.cs' Application_Start method.

Yet, although I have in my references Castle.Core and Castle.Windsor, WindsorDependencyResolver is not resolvable (how ironic is it that a Resolver is not being resolved).

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: How you instantiated your container? It should looks like `var container = new WindsorContainer();`

Comment: Please see my edited code (I added that, but it makes no difference).

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "WindsorDependencyResolver is not resolvable". How are you resolving it?

Comment: I'm not yet; I'm adding the code a bit at a time, and this is all I've got so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WindsorDependencyResolver` is not a class shipped with Castle Windsor.  It's a custom class that the author of the original post you referenced wrote.  His [page](http://blog.mirajavora.com/getting-started-with-asp.net-web-api) has a link to his [GitHub project](https://github.com/mirajavora/WebAPISample) that contains the source code for the blog post -- including the `WindsorDependencyResolver`.